# Hadoop 2.6.0 TestDFSIO benchmark

Tags: hadoop, benchmarking

So I have set up a hadoop 2.6.0 cluster and I want to run a benchmark to test read a write throughput. I keep reading places that I can use TestDFSIO to do this, but I am not able to find a way to run this program on Hadoop version 2.6.0. Does anyone know how to run this test, or an alternative?

Answer (score 2):

HiBench has an implementation of DFSIO.  You can find HiBench by clicking [here](https://github.com/intel-hadoop/HiBench/tree/master).

Answer (score -1):

You can run TestDFSIO benchmark test in hadoop 2.6.0 by the following command:

$ hadoop jar /usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient-2.6.0-tests.jar TestDFSIO -write -nrFiles 10 -fileSize 100

For detailed description you can also visit http://researchbyomesh.blogspot.in/2015/12/running-benchmark-tests-in-hadoop.html