# Hadoop: is it possible to run TestDFSIO benchmark as non-hdfs user

Tags: hadoop, benchmarking

Is it possible to execute TestDFSIO benchmark as non-hdfs user? This benchmark is trying to create a /benchmarks directory and fails because of lack of permissions. Is there a way to make this benchmark use my hdfs home to store data?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27324972/hadoop-2-6-0-testdfsio-benchmark

Comment: This is not a duplicate. The person in the other question is asking where can he find the benchmark. I already have it localized in hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient-x.y.z-cdh5.a.b-tests.jar. I'd like to use this codebase, not HiBench one (that is suggested in the answer to the other question).

Answer (score 1):

Should be possible by setting the configuration parameter "test.build.data", which defaults to "/benchmarks/TestDFSIO".

(see: https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/release-2.6.0/hadoop-mapreduce-project/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient/src/test/java/org/apache/hadoop/fs/TestDFSIO.java#L178)

It looks like TestDFSIO consults 4 config files for its Configuration, so hopefully putting the parameter in any one of those would do the trick:

hdfs-default.xml, hdfs-site.xml, mapred-default.xml, mapred-site.xml

(see https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/release-2.6.0/hadoop-mapreduce-project/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient/src/test/java/org/apache/hadoop/fs/TestDFSIO.java#L111-L114)